# Is there an equivalent function in PHP for unix cut -f?

Tags: php, cut

I have a long string of values separated by tabs and I wish to cut the data as if using unix cut -f. If I use cut -f5 it cuts all my data into a single column of the value which is in the 5th position. Is there a PHP function that can do the same?

Below is an example of the raw file with each word in the row separated by a tab

[image]

The result would be as follows if I ran cut -f2:

[image]

Comment: can you post input and desired output.

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) or [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). The manual is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer really is "no", as far as I know. But you can combine a few PHP functions to achieve the same result.

You can use `file` to read the lines from the file into an array

```
$rows = file($path_to_your_file);
```

Then convert that array of strings to a multidimensional array

```
$rows = array_map(function($row){
    return str_getcsv($row, "\t");
}, $rows);
```

Then get the column you want from that array.

```
$column_5 = array_column($rows, 4);
```

Not as concise as `cut -f5`, but PHP rarely is for things like this.

Incidentally, if you don't care that your PHP program will only work on systems that have unix cut, you can actually just use the cut -f in `shell_exec`.

Comment: Thanks but its not working for me. I will show you my results in a sec.

Comment: @NeverPhased The arrays returned by `str_getcsv` will be zero indexed, so you'll need to use the number of the column you want -1 in `array_column`. So for the example you added, it would be 1 in order to get the cut -f2 result.

Comment: Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /Users/myusername/index.php on line 10

Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Users/myusername/index.php on line 11

Comment: $filecont = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
$rows = $filecont;
$rows = array_map(function($row){
    return str_getcsv($row, "\t");
}, $rows);
$column = array_column($rows, 1);
echo $column;

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm feeding the file in? I am feeding the content of the file from command line to $argv[1] and setting it to $filecont...

Comment: The argument you pass to the PHP `file` function should be a string with the path to your file, not the actual contents of the file. I showed it as a variable in the answer because I don't know the path. I'm sorry if that was misleading. I changed the variable name to be more clear what I meant.

Comment: Hmm yes I think its clear. I havn't used it because I have the contents of the file in $filecont as a string. So then I go straight to $rows = $filecont; $rows = array_map(function..... yet I'm getting the error I posted as the 3rd comment here. Any ideas?